# saving data from a failing drive

Tags: hard-disk, data-recovery, dd

An external 3½" HDD seems to be in danger of failing — it's making [ticking sounds when idle](https://superuser.com/questions/226369/3-pata-western-digital-caviar-se-250mb-makes-steady-ticking-sound-when-idle/226370#226370).

I've acquired a replacement drive, and want to know the best strategy to get the data off of the dubious drive with the best chance of saving as much as possible.

There are some directories that are more important than others.  However, I'm guessing that picking and choosing directories is going to reduce my chances of saving the whole thing.  I would also have to mount it, dump a file listing, and then unmount it in order to be able to effectively prioritize directories.  Adding in the fact that it's time-consuming to do this, I'm leaning away from this approach.

I've considered just using `dd`, but I'm not sure how it would handle read errors or other problems that might prevent only certain parts of the data from being rescued, or which could be overcome with some retries, but not so many that they endanger other parts of the drive from being saved.  I guess ideally it would do a single pass to get as much as possible and then go back to retry anything that was missed due to errors.

Is it possible that copying more slowly — e.g. pausing every x MB/GB — would be better than just running the operation full tilt, for example to avoid any overheating issues?

For the "where is your backup" crowd: this actually is my backup drive, but it also contains some non-critical and bulky stuff, like music, that aren't backups, i.e. aren't backed up.

The drive has not exhibited any clear signs of failure other than this somewhat ominous sound.  I did have to fsck a few errors recently — orphaned inodes, incorrect free blocks/inodes counts, inode bitmap differences, zero dtime on deleted inodes; about 20 errors in all.

The filesystem of the partition is ext3.

Comment: cross-posted on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19297/saving-data-from-a-failing-drive) and [superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/227010/saving-data-from-a-failing-drive)

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`ddrescue`](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html) or [`dd_rescue`](http://www.garloff.de/kurt/linux/ddrescue/) or [`myrescue`](http://myrescue.sourceforge.net/) to clone the failing disk, without aborting on any unreadable sector. (Myrescue is less configurable but has a better default strategy as it tries to skip over unreadable regions.) This will copy everything including blank space and won't let you set priorities. However, such a low-level approach has an advantage over filesystem-level tools: if a directory is unreadable, you might still recover the files it contains by searching the raw image with tools such as [`foremost`](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/), [`magicrescue`](https://www.itu.dk/~jobr/magicrescue/), `photorec` included in [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), etc.

Comment: The link for `magicrescue` seems to be broken; did you mean https://www.itu.dk/~jobr/magicrescue/ instead?

Comment: @landroni Yes, I guess this student graduated, thanks.

Comment: "Myrescue [..] has a better default strategy" Would you consider posting a `ddrescue` example configured with the `myrescue` defaults? Thanks!

Comment: For `ddrescue`/`dd_rescue` you make first pass with large block size and change to smaller in the following passes (e.g. halving the size each time). This of  course requires you to use a logfile (see man page).

Comment: Confusingly, on Debian-based systems the command `ddrescue` comes from package `gddrescue`; `dd_rescue` from package `ddrescue`; and `myrescue` from package `myrescue`.

Comment: @peterph I am now reading the [docs of gddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Algorithm) and it seems to me that by default `ddrescue` does behave mostly like `myrescue`. In short: `ddrescue` reads the non-tried parts *in large blocks*, and skips the failed blocks (marking them as such) but also the slow areas. It then returns to the tried&failed areas, and reads each non-read sector one by one. Not *exactly* like `myrescue`, but pretty similar, is it not?

Comment: @Gilles Actually from the `gddrescue` docs, `ddrescue` initially skips over unreadable or slow-reading areas.

Answer (score 8):

There's no way of knowing the best of your options without knowing exactly what is going wrong with the drive. If it's a mechanical failure, avoiding heating it up can help, but if it's due to errors in the servo data, heat isn't likely to matter.

I would immediately start copying the unique data to the new drive with `rsync`.  `rsync` will let you pause, resume, and restart as necessary until you get all the data off.

Then I would run a data scrub on the drive. I assume from the `ext3` filesystem that you're running Linux, so try this:

```
# umount /dev/sdX
# badblocks -n /dev/sdX
```

(Unmounting the drive first is important.)

This will read every sector from the disk and write it back without change. That will force the drive firmware to check every sector for errors and to remap any bad sectors it finds. This is the most important part of what the expensive [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) program does. Step up to that only if `badblocks` fails and you still haven't gotten all the unique data off the drive: SpinRite tries harder than `badblocks` does.

Answer (score 2):

If the disk is dying, **first make sure you make as good clone of it as you can** (see Gilles answer) and *only then* proceed to playing with the drive. That way you'll always have at least some data, in case something goes wrong (which can often happen with a failing hardware).

If you use `ddrescue` (or `dd_rescue`, I'm not sure about the others), you can always make a copy of the partially cloned data **and the associated logfile** and try to improve it by running `ddrescue` again after doing something that was supposed to fix the drive. It will try to read the missing parts while leaving the well-cloned parts untouched.